# Display as Label Text

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Instead of displaying the following in an popup box I want to display it as a label text.

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowCurrentTime() {
PageMethods.GetCurrentTime(document.getElementById("<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>").value, OnSuccess);
}
function OnSuccess(response, userContext, methodName) {
alert(response);
}
</script>
```

Label

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you're going to want to examine the actual HTML markup that gets rendered to the browser.  Any time you're working with JavaScript, understand that the JavaScript interacts with the *result* of the ASP.NET server-side controls, not the controls themselves.

Assuming this `asp:Label` renders as some HTML element, something like this ought to do the trick:

```
$('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').text(response);
```

It's essentially using the same concept your existing code already uses, identifying an element based on its server-side control's `ClientID` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').text(response);
or document.getElementbyId('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').value = response;
```

Refer to [Jquery manipulating elements](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/) for more info on how to select and modify elemetns easily on the client side